# Javascript execution: Understanding how Compilation and Interpretation steps work?

Tags: javascript, compilation, interpretation

I recently learned how javascript executes the code in two steps: firstly the compilation and then the interpretation step.
I learned that the compilation phase only registers (takes into account) the variables (and function name) in the entire code and ignores what is assigned to these vars.

Once it is completed with its job, the interpreter goes line by line and does the final job of assigning the values and executing the functions that compiler has registered in previous phase.

Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

With this understanding, I have a minor query.

Consider the following code:

```
console.log(a);
a = 10;     // not var a = 10;
```

The compilation phase will ignore line 1, but will it also ignore line 2 which has no variable declaration? Instead, line 2 straight away writes to an undeclared variable `a`. Since this is a write operation on an undeclared variable, JS doesn't give an error but creates a new Global variable `a`.

Now, my question is how would the compilation and interpretation phase run through this code? Is it the compiler or the interpreter phase that creates this variable `a` in global scope?
If compiler did not register `var a` on line 2, shouldn't the interpreter give an error when it tries to read an undeclared variable `a` on line 1?  Even if it did create a Global variable on line 1, shouldn't the interpreter then print `undefined`,  since the compiler can't assign 10 to it?

In a nutshell, when will this global variable be created and the value 10 assigned to it?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the code you provided would result in an error during runtime. Let's go through the compilation and interpretation phases to understand why.

1. Compilation Phase:
   During the compilation phase, the JavaScript engine analyzes the code and prepares it for execution. It identifies variables and functions and sets up the necessary memory space for them. However, it does not assign any values to variables at this stage.
   In your code, the compiler recognizes the presence of the variable a in the `console.log(a)` statement. However, since there is no `var`, `let`, or `const` keyword before it, the compiler does not register `a` as a variable.
2. Interpretation Phase:
   During the interpretation phase, the JavaScript engine executes the code line by line.
   In your code, when the interpreter encounters the line `console.log(a);`, it attempts to find the value of `a`. Since the variable `a` was not declared with `var`, `let`, or `const`, the interpreter throws a ReferenceError because it cannot find the variable `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Mani, I recently learned this too and found it definitely interesting. I understood that JS read files from top-to-bottom but this was new knowledge for me. I think this video helped me understand the actual execution down to the compiler process in much detail. It is from FreeCodeCamp and about 10 mins with a solid diagram. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xckH5s3UuX4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).